# NextJS best practice for handling "Server Error" and "Client side error"

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js, server-error

Using NextJS, I see 2 kinds of errors:

**Server Error**

- generated it using `throw new Error(...)` inside getInitialProps...
- it can occur due to some business logic or unexpected API response;
- screenshot:

[image: Server error]

**Unhandled Runtime Error**

- generated it using `throw new Error(...)` inside a component
- it can occur due to some business logic;
- the error here is captured by the ErrorBoundary (which is set inside `_app.js`)
- screenshot:

[image: Unhandled Runtime Error]

**Question**:
unhandled run time errors are captured inside Error Boundary (as they do in ReactJS)... how to best handle the 'server errors'... what is the best practice?

Comment: Did you make any progress here or can share any resource on how to best handle errors? I am baffled by the frameworks behavior.

Comment: Have try catch blocks on every API call... try to test each input to getInitialProps or getStaticProps to handle null, error and exception values; these coding practices (albeit very basic) are an important basic step in order to get a reliable working app

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practices to handle errors is use Early Return, by returning a `statusCode` prop inside of the getInitialProps and use that `statusCode` to render the error page after render the page to prevent handle the posible errors inside the page.

- If everything is ok 200
- If does not exist 404
- If server error 503

```
import Error from "next/error"

function Page({ stars, statusCode}) {
  
  if(statusCode !== 200) {
    return <Error statusCode={statusCode} />
  }
  
  return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
}

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  
  try{
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
    const json = await res.json()
    
    if(res.status >= 400){
      return { stars: json.stargazers_count, statusCode: res.status }
    }
    
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count, statusCode: 200 }
   
    
  } catch(error){
    
    return {stars: null, statusCode: 503}
  }
  
}

export default Page
```